# Specification of feeds of Apple App Store reviews

Tags: app-store

I am looking for the specification of feeds of App Store reviews.

(e.g. reviews feed)
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=471339479/sortBy=mostRecent/xml

I want to know whether there are any other options/parameters or not.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We just released https://launchkit.io/reviews/ and spent a lot of times with these feeds. I think what you see is what you get. We haven't found anything else that's helpful.

Comment: Please be careful with product recommendations. Right now 1/3 of your answers are just links to this product (which you presumably developed/work for the company). Its not spam... yet. Answer more questions, and try to flesh these out with how to use that product. Also be a bit more clear with your affiliation.

Comment: thanks @BradleyDotNET.. i tried to be as clear as possible that i was affiliated by saying "We just released". But thanks for the feedback and i'll make sure to include more

Comment: Thats not *quite* an affiliation statement, but I figured thats what you meant :) With this kind of thing, we are a bit.... touchy, so clearer is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can change country origin /us/ to /gb/, add pagination /customerreviews/page=1/ and finally display it in json format mostRecent/xml to mostRecent/json (but you will not be able to see date info)